# Call a function after a time interval, each time with updated arguments

Tags: erlang

I have a packet, if it contains a particular tag (say testtag) then i need to wait for some time before implementing a particular function (say testfunction) with argument value from packet's tag (say valuetag), but if during that timeout that packet comes again but with different valuetag, then implement the testfunction with updated value.
How to implement this?

Answer (score 1):

Usually, it is required to show what you tried so far. But I found the problem cool so I propose you a solution. Very few comments, but I think it is relatively easy to read. (I let you find how to extract the function test name and the params from a packet and call the user inerface)

```
-module (test_tag).


-export ([start/0,activate/3,modify/2,remove/1,stop/0]).

-export ([test_server/1,proc_server/3]).

-export ([test1/2,test2/3]).

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% User Interface

% start the test with an empty map of pending test process
start() ->
    Pid = spawn(?MODULE, test_server, [#{}]),
    register(test_server, Pid).

activate(TestName,ParamList,Timeout) when 
    is_atom(TestName), is_list(ParamList), is_number(Timeout) ->
    test_server ! {activate,TestName,ParamList,Timeout}.

modify(TestName,ParamList) when is_atom(TestName), is_list(ParamList) ->
    test_server ! {modify,TestName,ParamList}.

remove(TestName) when is_atom(TestName) ->
    test_server ! {remove,TestName}.

stop() ->
    test_server ! stop.

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% internal interface

completed(TestName) ->
    test_server ! {completed,TestName,self()}.

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Sever loop (receive user request and organize the job)

% test_server(stop | map())
test_server(stop) ->
    io:format("stopped by user~n");
test_server(Pending) ->
    NewPending = receive 
        {activate,TestName,ParamList,Timeout} ->
            activate_test(TestName,ParamList,Timeout,Pending);
        {modify,TestName,ParamList} ->
            modify_test(TestName,ParamList,Pending);
        {remove,TestName} ->
            remove_test(TestName,Pending);
        {completed,TestName,Pid} ->
            test_complete(TestName,Pid,Pending);
        stop -> stop_test(Pending)
    end,
    test_server(NewPending).

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% helper functions (in charge to do the server job)

activate_test(TestName,ParamList,Timeout,Pending) ->
    case maps:is_key(TestName, Pending) of 
        true ->
            io:format("test ~p already started~n",[TestName]),
            Pending; %do nothing
        false ->
            Pid = spawn(?MODULE,proc_server,[TestName,ParamList,Timeout]),
            maps:put(TestName, Pid, Pending)
    end.

modify_test(TestName,ParamList,Pending) ->
    case maps:get(TestName, Pending,undefined) of 
        undefined ->
            io:format("test ~p not started~n",[TestName]);
        Pid ->
            Pid ! {new_param,TestName,ParamList}
    end,
    Pending. % Map unchanged.

remove_test(TestName,Pending) ->
    case maps:get(TestName, Pending,undefined) of 
        undefined ->
            io:format("test ~p not started~n",[TestName]),
            Pending;
        Pid ->
            Pid ! {stop,TestName},
            maps:remove(TestName, Pending)
    end.

test_complete(TestName,Pid,Pending) ->
    case maps:get(TestName, Pending,undefined) of 
        undefined ->
            Pending; % already removed, presumably by user
        Pid ->
            Pid ! {stop,TestName},
            maps:remove(TestName, Pending)
    end.


stop_test(Pending) ->
    maps:map(fun(TestName,Pid) -> Pid ! {stop,TestName} end, Pending),
    stop. % return stop to end the test server loop

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

% init the process in charge to execute a test after a while
proc_server(TestName,ParamList,Timeout) ->
    timer:send_after(Timeout, self(), {execute,TestName}),
    proc_server(TestName,ParamList).

% listening loop
proc_server(TestName,ParamList) ->
    receive 
        {execute,TestName} -> 
            catch(apply(?MODULE,TestName, ParamList)),
            completed(TestName);
        {new_param,TestName,NewParamList} ->
            proc_server(TestName,NewParamList);
        {stop,TestName} ->
            io:format("test ~p stopped\n",[TestName]),
            stop
    end.

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% User tests

test1(Param1,Param2) ->
    io:format("executing test1 with params ~p and ~p ~n",[Param1,Param2]).

test2(Param1,Param2,Param3) ->
    io:format("executing test2 with params ~p, ~p and ~p~n",[Param1,Param2,Param3]).
```

Execution in the shell

```
1> c(test_tag).                                   
{ok,test_tag}
 test_tag:start().                              
true
2> test_tag:activate(test1,[hello,"hello"],20000).
{activate,test1,[hello,"hello"],20000}
3> test_tag:modify(test1,[hello,"hello guys"]).   
{modify,test1,[hello,"hello guys"]}
executing test1 with params hello and "hello guys" 
4> test_tag:activate(test1,[hello,"hello"],20000).
{activate,test1,[hello,"hello"],20000}
5> test_tag:activate(test1,[hello,"hello"],20000).
test test1 already started
{activate,test1,[hello,"hello"],20000}
executing test1 with params hello and "hello"       
6> test_tag:remove(test1).                        
test test1 not started
{remove,test1}
7> test_tag:activate(test1,[hello,"hello"],20000).
{activate,test1,[hello,"hello"],20000}
8> test_tag:remove(test1).                        
test test1 stopped
{remove,test1}
9> test_tag:activate(test2,[hello,"hello",12],20).   
{activate,test2,[hello,"hello",12],20}
executing test2 with params hello, "hello" and 12
10> test_tag:activate(test2,[hello,"hello"],20).   
{activate,test2,[hello,"hello"],20}
11> test_tag:activate(test2,[hello,"hello"],20000).
{activate,test2,[hello,"hello"],20000}
12> test_tag:activate(test2,[hello,"hello"],20000).
test test2 already started
{activate,test2,[hello,"hello"],20000}
13> test_tag:remove(test2).                        
test test2 stopped
{remove,test2}
14> test_tag:activate(test3,[hello,"hello"],20000).
{activate,test3,[hello,"hello"],20000}
15> %wait 20 sec
15> test_tag:remove(test3).                        
test test3 not started
{remove,test3}
16>
```

Comment: I am particularly new with erlang could you please explain why on calling with the new_param, still the timeout occurs at the original end time only

Comment: It is because I thought it was your intent. If you want to restart a complete timeout, it is necessary, in the modify_test function to cancel the current timeout using the function timer:cancel(Tref) and restart a new one. For this, the proc_server loop need to store the Tref returned by timer:send_after/3, and also to store the timeout parameter (or add it to the modify interface).